# How to call the single product template into another page template in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Goal: Create a Woocommerce page where we can have multiple products with all the details of a single product page(not just image and title like the shop page). This would ultimately replace the 'product page'.

My thought was to be able to call the single product template for each product within a loop on one page. But i'm unsure how to call the single product template within a different template.
thanks,

Edit: It would be very similar to this page: https://legionathletics.com/products/supplements/whey/
the page has multiple products(single pack, 3 pack) with variations.

Comment: So you don't want to use shop page template as it is. Is that right? I mean you want to customize shop page to have more detailed products… Another question: What kind (type) of products are you planing to use. Your question as it is, is just to broad, so please edit it, to make it more precise, telling what you want to display, and what type of product you plan to use.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec great, I added an example

Comment: You haven't really clarified your question enough / detailed (if you rely want to get helped), and haven't really ask to my questions… I you want people making an effort answering, you need to make also an effort when asking.